# symfony form does not process my search filters

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have created a search form in symfony to allow me to search for a term in a title or content of my Media entity or to search by Category.
The form is well processed via the MediasController, my findWithSearch function is created in the MediaRepository and the form is displayed in the Medias/index.html.twig template.
In the debugger, the query seems to work fine but the filtering is not done on the page, if someone could tell me why

Repository of project:
https://github.com/Eosia/blog-symf/blob/main/src/Controller/MediasController.php

Answer (score 0):

This is because on line 56 you do:

```php
$donnees = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Media::class)->findBy([],['id' => 'desc']);
```

Which is used by your page to display the results.
And you never use the data filtered by the form on line 46.